# Perl - return from child using system 1 approach

Tags: perl, command

I'm calling a child script from my main script with below command:

```
system 1, "perl C:\\test.pl";
```

I want to know how can I return a value from above child to my main script?
Can somebody please help?

Comment: Do you mean the exit status of the command? Or the output of the command?

Comment: `system 1,...` is a Windows hack to run a command "in the background". [See `perlport`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlport#system).

Comment: using "system 1" I create a child which can run in parallel to main script. I need to know in this way if my child could return a value to my main script?

Answer (score 1):

You should instead open the child perl with a pipe and read what it prints to standard output:

```
open(F, "-|", 'perl C:\test.pl') or die;
my $data = <F>;  # Gets one line of output.
```

To use `system` you will have to set up a pipe or socket connection on your own, which is a bit involved, or else use a file to pass the data.

A little test that shows parent and child running in parallel.  In `child.pl`,

```
# Simulate a long computation
for ('a'..'k') {
  print STDERR "$_ ";
  sleep 1;
}
# This goes to the pipe.
print "Hello world! ";
```

In `parent.pl`,

```
open(F, "-|", 'perl child.pl') or die;
# Child is running.  Do a long computation in the parent.
for (1..10) {
  print STDERR "$_ ";
  sleep 1
}
# Now get the final value from the child's pipe.
my $data = <F>;
print STDERR $data;
close F;
```

Then:

```
C:\tmp>perl parent.pl
1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e 6 f 7 g 8 h 9 i 10 j k Hello world!
```

Comment: Actually i want to run child in parallel to my main script. i use "system 1" to achieve it. This way my child start in paraller and at the same time I start proceed in my main script. i want to know when child has completed its task, can it retun a value to main script?

Comment: You can run parent and child in parallel with my code.  The parent will not block until it tries to read the value from the child and there's nothing written yet.  The child will generate output until the pipe buffer is full.  No matter what method you use, the parent and child must rendezvous to exchange data through a buffer in this manner.

Comment: @user2684591 I changed to code to show how both processes run in parallel until they rendezvous.